# Correct way for a db_query for nodes between two timestamps

Tags: datetime, database

I have a very simple db_query.  I want to look for any node created between two timestamps.

This query works fine in MySQL shell

```
SELECT nid as id,created as start,title FROM node WHERE created BETWEEN '1403564400' AND '1403650800';
```

This works fine in Drupal

```
$data = db_query("SELECT nid as id,created as start,title FROM node")->fetchAll();
echo json_encode($data);
```

As soon as I add in the BETWEEN conditions below I get an Internal Server Error.

```
$data = db_query("SELECT nid as id,created as start,title FROM node WHERE created BETWEEN '1403564400' AND '1403650800'")->fetchAll();
```

I am unsure what I am doing wrong here, perhaps someone can point me in the right direction please!

Answer (score 6):

You can try using db_select instead wich is a better way to create query with Drupal (assuming you are using Drupal 7).

```
$start_time = '1403564400';
$end_time = '1403650800';
$query = db_select('node', 'n')
  ->fields('n', array('nid', 'created', 'title'))
  ->condition('created', array($start_time, $end_time), 'BETWEEN');
$result = $query->execute();
$record = $result->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Thank you - I have been told that db_select is slower and for critical performance related tasks, db_query is the better option.  I also only wnated to use DRUPAL_BOOTSTRAP_DATABASE for this task as I need to retrieve this data quickly and did not want to do a full Drupal boostrap call.

Comment: My mistake, db_query was working, I just had some wrong code elsewhere.

Comment: Ok, but beware when using db_query to escape your vars. Glad your problem was solved :-D

Comment: Use placeholders instead of escaping your variables.  These work in `db_query()`.  Also, if you are querying against the `{node}` table you should just about always use a `db_select()` with `->addTag('node_access')` to make sure you don't have a permission bypass problem.